# Unable to display image in PHP generated emails linked from Mad File Manager

Tags: php, email, tinymce

I have this option whereby the admin can upload files, eg. pictures to the server using Mad File Manager. The "installation" of the File Manager works.

The problem occurs when I want to send an email using PHP, composed the email using TinyMCE, included the picture using the full URL, it shows... but then, when the email arrives at the other end, the image doesn't show.

What I found out is that, eg.

my domain: `www.emailtest.com`
upload folder: `uploads`

The url reflected from the image at the recipient's end only shows: `uploads/image.jpg` when it should be `www.emailtest.com/uploads/image.jpg` right?

The domain's name has been truncated.

Can anyone give me a lead on how to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: rewrite the the `<img src=` before sending the email to have the full url, or embed the images in the email

Comment: The admin uses TinyMCE's image linking feature to attach the image. The thing is that the admin is not so "IT savy" so yea... trying to make it simple for them... =(

Comment: sounds like 'they' have the right approach, you simply need to tweak your email sending code.

Comment: The code that's what made them able to use TinyMCE... it is just the image not displaying at the the recipient's end...

Comment: is there a point to this discussion? i told you what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you will need to tweak the tinymce configuration settings a bit.
Have a look at the [relative_urls](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3arelative_urls) param.